# python script to play audio from RaspberryPi using vlc

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, libvlc

I am tyring to get a list of songs running on my RaspberryPi at the same time every day. For that I have written a python script and plan to run that as a cronjob.

The script I have written is below.

```
import vlc
import glob
import time

base_folder = '/home/pi/Music/'


def play_song(song):
    player = vlc.MediaPlayer(song)
    player.play()

    
def add_media(player, media_list, playlist):
    for song in playlist:
        print('sing " {0}'.format(song))
        media = player.media_new(song)    
        media_list.add_media(media)
        
    media_player.set_media_list(media_list)

  
playlist = glob.glob(base_folder + "/" + "*.mp3")
media_player = vlc.MediaListPlayer()
player = vlc.Instance()    
media_list = vlc.MediaList()
add_media(player, media_list, playlist)
```

I have one issue with the above program.

When I run the python program from `Thonny` which is the default python IDE for RaspberryPi it works. (i.e it plays the songs). However when I run this from the command line as

```
python3 audioplayer.py
```

it exits without playing the songs. How do I make it play the songs while running from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be missing some code in your posted script i.e. the `play` command.

I suspect that the IDE is holding the main loop open for `vlc`, thus it works.
However, from the command line, there is no loop, that is what you are missing.

Try the following:

```
import vlc
import glob
import time

base_folder = '/home/rolf'
# vlc State 0: Nowt, 1 Opening, 2 Buffering, 3 Playing, 4 Paused, 5 Stopped, 6 Ended, 7 Error
playing = set([1,2,3,4])

def add_media(inst, media_list, playlist):
    for song in playlist:
        print('Loading: - {0}'.format(song))
        media = inst.media_new(song)    
        media_list.add_media(media)
        
playlist = glob.glob(base_folder + "/" + "*.mp3")
playlist = sorted(playlist)
#playlist = ['./2005.mp3', './vp1.mp3']
media_player = vlc.MediaListPlayer()
inst = vlc.Instance('--no-xlib --quiet ') 
media_list = vlc.MediaList()
add_media(inst, media_list, playlist)

media_player.set_media_list(media_list)
media_player.play()
time.sleep(0.1)
current = ""
idx = 1
player = media_player.get_media_player()
while True:
    state = player.get_state()
    if state.value not in playing:
        break
    title = player.get_media().get_mrl()
    if title != current:
        print("\nPlaying - {0}\t{1} of {2}".format(str(title), idx, len(playlist)))
        current = title
        idx += 1
    time.sleep(1.0)
print("\nPlaylist Finished")
```